# Is there an alternative for pyspark.ml.feature StringIndexer in python using pandas, numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

StringIndexer encodes a string column of labels to a column of label indices.

```
id | category | categoryIndex
----|----------|---------------
 0  | a        | 0.0
 1  | b        | 2.0
 2  | c        | 1.0
 3  | a        | 0.0
 4  | a        | 0.0
 5  | c        | 1.0
```

How to achieve this in python without using pyspark.ml.feature StringIndexer ?

Comment: Why is a = 0 but c =  1? And yeah, you can use `pd.factorize`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention `pandas`, try using ngroup

```
df.groupby('category').ngroup()
Out[564]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    2
dtype: int64
```